# Issue with VBA array Filter function: only first result is returned

Tags: vba, excel

I am running into some issues while using VBA its 'Filter' function. I am trying to use multiple subsequent filters to step by step reduce the array down the contain the value I need. It however seems that only the first element that matches the 'Match' value is returned and not the subsequent ones?

To given an example, when running the code below, the second 'debug call' return '1' but it should return '2'

```
Function FilterAnArray()

Dim names As Variant
names = Array("Ann Smith", "Barry Jones", "John Smith", "Stephen Brown", "Wilfred Cross")
Debug.Print UBound(names)

Dim smithNames As Variant
smithNames = Filter(names, "Smith")
Debug.Print UBound(smithNames)

End Function
```

**Version information e.t.c.**

I am running Excel 2016, version 16.0.8730.2046 - 64-bit. 
Any help with this issue is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It is working quite ok. It is returning 1, because you have two Smith's:

[image]

And the Upper bound of smithNames is 1, because it arrays are 0-based. If you want the count of the array elements, and you do not like the `UBound+1`, you may use a worksheet function:

`Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountA(smithNames)`

---

**Strongly not adviseable option:**

You may consider writing `Option Base 1` on the top of the module. Then the arrays will be 1-based and will be the way you expect it. In your example you see why `Option Base 1` is not advisable. If you have it, `Names` will be `1 based` and `smithNames` will be `0 based`. This is because of the different way the arrays are assigned.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why dou you think it is 'srongly' not advisable to use option base 1? In my opinion there are 3 kinds of arrays. 1) arrays that are always 0-based like split 2) arrays that are always 1-based like arrays from ranges and 3) arrays where you set either 3a) implicitly with option base or 3b) explicitly with dim dmy(3 to 7) which base they have. So it kinda depends on your case whats the best setup. I like the option base 1. Just my 2 cents ;-)

Comment: Only real problem I encountered is if you reuse code and have one module with option base 1 and one without. So +1 for: Its best if you set explicitly set your boundaries.

Comment: @Jochen - if you use `Option Base 1` and you share your code to someone, get ready for lots of trouble.

Comment: If I share my code, I share it with the option base 1 and with option explicit ;-)

Comment: @Jochen - `Option Explicit` is quite ok, but the `Option Base 1` can cause you problems. But this is another subject.

Answer (score 2):

Ubound gives the uppfer bound. As you use 0-based arrays you get a result of 4 for 5 entries and a result of 1 for 2 entries.

If you want to use 1-based array without explicitly dimensionen each array use `Option Base 1` at the beginning of you Module.

Comment: Ok, yes. And that in fact also was the error in the wider script I was trying to fix.  Sorry, this really was not a very clever question. You guys really helped me though!

Answer (score 0):

How about checking how many results you ought to get and then printing them, such as:

```
Sub foo()
Dim val As Variant
Dim names As Variant
Dim post As Variant
names = Array("Ann Smith", "Barry Jones", "John Smith", "Stephen Brown", "Wilfred Cross")
Debug.Print UBound(names)

Dim smithNames As Variant
smithNames = Filter(names, "Smith")

pos = Application.Match(smithNames, names, False) 'find how many values match "Smith"

If Not IsError(pos) Then
    For x = LBound(pos) To UBound(pos)
        Debug.Print pos(x)
    Next x
Else
   MsgBox val & " not found!"
End If
End Sub
```